# How to stop matrix builds on the first error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a CI pipeline setup for release and debug builds:

```yaml
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - "master"
      - "main"
      - "feature/*"
      - "hotfix/*"

strategy:
  matrix: 
    'Release':
      buildConfiguration: 'Release'
    'Debug':
      buildConfiguration: 'Debug'
```

Both are ran regardless of errors:

[image]

I want to change this behaviour so that when one job fails the other job also stops - saving me build minutes.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not have any built-in method can easily automatically cancel all in-progress jobs if any matrix job fails.

As a workaround, you can try the following method:

- Add a script task (such as [**PowerShell**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) or [**Bash**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops)) as the last step of the matrix job.
- Set the script task runs when any of the previous tasks is failed (**`condition: failed()`**).
- On the script task, set the script to execute the REST API "[**Builds - Update Build**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/update-build?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)" to cancel current build.

With this way, when any task in the job is failed, the script task will run and execute the REST API to cancel the whole build.

Of course, if you really want a built-in easy method can be used (for example, add the option **`jobs.job.strategy.fail-fast`**), I recommend that you can report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion). That will make it possible for you to interact with the appropriate engineering team, and make it more convenient for the engineering team to collect and categorize your suggestions.

Comment: Hm - too bad but thanks for your support!